# ChartJS - How to provide datasets an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chart.js

I have an array of objects and want to provide it to the datasets variable but I'm unsure how to...

It works if I do the following but I can't seem to code up a loop that can do this in 1 line.

```html
new Chart(canvas, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    datasets: [

        chartData.datasets[0],
        chartData.datasets[1],
        chartData.datasets[2],
        chartData.datasets[3],
        chartData.datasets[4],
        chartData.datasets[5],
        chartData.datasets[6],
        chartData.datasets[7],
        chartData.datasets[8],
        chartData.datasets[9],
        chartData.datasets[10],
        chartData.datasets[11],
        chartData.datasets[12],
        chartData.datasets[13],
        chartData.datasets[14],
        chartData.datasets[15],
        chartData.datasets[16],
        chartData.datasets[17],
        chartData.datasets[18],
        chartData.datasets[19],
        chartData.datasets[20],
        chartData.datasets[21],
        chartData.datasets[22],
        chartData.datasets[23]
    ]
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],

        // chartData.datasets is an array
        datasets: chartData.datasets,

    },
```

Comment: That doesn't work as datasets contains an array of objects so it includes the array keys. What I need are the objects excluding the array keys.

Comment: how do you generate the array `chartData.datasets` ?

Answer (score 0):

Juan's answer will do what you want. If, for some reason, you only want 0 to 23, you can pass `chartData.datasets.slice(0, 24)` instead of `chartData.datasets`.

**EDIT**

```
let data = [];
chartData.datasets.forEach(a => data = data.concat(a));
```

And pass `data` instead.

This will concatenate every entry in `chartData.datasets`

Comment: It won't work as datasets contains an array of objects. I need the objects without the array keys and using chartData.datasets doesn't do that. I have included an image in my original question that will help explain the problem further.

Comment: That's creating exactly the same thing as I have mate. The same structure as shown in the pic in my original post.

Comment: It's not. This is concatting all of them. datasets: data

Comment: When I console.log the result I've got the same thing. 24 arrays containing objects.

Comment: Look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezsxctur/ Maybe show the structure of one of the entries.

Comment: I've sorted it mate. Absolute noob mistake by me... charts.datasets works, I just needed to make sure it wasn't contained with brackets. So the answer is... datasets: charts.dataset as opposed to datasets:[charts.dataset]

Comment: Haha it happens, no problem :)